# Accessing Bind Variable in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, buffer, bind-variables, ora-06502

I am trying to run a program in the Oracle express edition editor.  When I execute the program, I get an error

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
```

Can anyone help me understand why I am getting an error and how to fix the code?

```
VARIABLE gvn_total_salary NUMBER;
DECLARE
   vn_base_salary NUMBER := 3000;
   vn_bonus NUMBER := 1000;
BEGIN
   :gvn_total_salary := vn_base_salary + vn_bonus;
END;
```

The output I'm getting

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small 


Run By SYSTEM 
Parsing Schema SYSTEM 
Script Started Thursday, April 26, 2012 
 3 seconds ago 
Elapsed time 0.01 seconds 
Statements Processed 1 
Successful 0 
With Errors 1
```

Comment: Where and how is gvn_total_salary defined?

Comment: ohh sorry.. it has got missed.  it is defined as bind variable                 ---   DECLARE
   vn_base_salary NUMBER := 3000;
   vn_bonus NUMBER := 1000;
BEGIN
   :gvn_total_salary := vn_base_salary + vn_bonus;
END;

Comment: while i am trying to execute it i'm getting before execution itself as---
 
Script Name sample bind 
Created on 04/26/2012 10:20:22 PM by SYSTEM  
Updated on 04/26/2012 10:20:59 PM by SYSTEM  
Number of Statements 1 
Script Size in Bytes 165 

Line Number Unknown Statement 
1 VARIABLE gvn_total_salary NUMBER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you actually trying to accomplish? This script won't execute in sqlplus or Oracle Developer or any PL/SQL execution environment I can think of. In fact, I don't understand how you are passing the bind variable :gvn_total_salary and how you can get the error you are describing. You should get something like "bind variable gvn_total_salary" not declared.

Answer (score 1):

With the declaration of the bind variable, that code works fine for me in SQL*Plus

```
SQL> VARIABLE gvn_total_salary NUMBER;
SQL> DECLARE
  2     vn_base_salary NUMBER := 3000;
  3     vn_bonus NUMBER := 1000;
  4  BEGIN
  5     :gvn_total_salary := vn_base_salary + vn_bonus;
  6  END;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print gvn_total_salary

GVN_TOTAL_SALARY
----------------
            4000
```

Can you connect to the database using SQL*Plus and run the same thing?

Comment: yes i can in sql* plus command line.  But i'm not able to get it done in Oracle express edition editor (in browser which opens in database home page after login)